# Description of a list of tables

Tags: r

I have a set of table in R and I want to audit them.
I would like to create a table containing each column of data.frame in memory, the data.frame and the type of the column.

Is there an existing function to do so?
And if I should wrote it myself, what is the best way?

As `str()` doesn't return any value, I think about `summary` + `lapply`.

But I don't manage to automatically find a list of data.frame.
`ls()` return a vector of objects, but I don't know how to apply `is.data.frame` to a string.

my session:

```
df1 <- data.frame(t = 1, t2 = "c")
df2 <- data.frame(t1 = TRUE, t4 = "j", stringsAsFactors = F)
df3 <- data.frame(dt = Sys.Date(), dt2 = Sys.time())
u <- "string"
```

The result I want:

```
audit <- data.frame(table = c(rep(df1, 2), rep(df2, 2), rep(df3, 2)
       , column = c("t", "t2", "t1", "t4", "dt", "dt2")
       , type = c("num", "Factor", "logi", "chr", "Date", "POSIXct"))
       , stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete verifiable example.

Comment: Try either `lapply(data_lst, summary)` or `lapply(mget(data_lst), summary)`. The first will work if the list is an R `?list` object, the second is for a series of data frame names in a `vector`.

Comment: @PierreLafortune sorry, I can't find the function data_lst.

Comment: @YCR I think `data_list` is a list of your dataframes int his context...

Comment: @Heroka, sorry, I can't find a data_list function. Even using Rseek.org. The closest one is data.list but don't do what I am looking for.

Comment: It is not a function. It is a made-up name for a list of your dataframes. `data_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)`.

Comment: sorry, it is not the point, here. I have a session with existing data.frame and in order to achieve their description, I want to create a list of all the data.frame of my session, and only the data.frame. The step after is to use a function combining summary(), names(), class(), etc. to describe each of them.

Comment: If you would like a list of all data.frames in your current session then, `indx <- sapply(mget(ls()), function(x) class(x) == "data.frame");mget(names(indx)[indx])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Is this close enough to what you want?

```
# returns a character vector of names of all data.frames in envir
data.frame.names <- function(envir = .GlobalEnv) {
    Filter(function(nam) is.data.frame(get(nam, envir)), ls(envir))
}

# returns character matrix with names, columns and types of data.frame 
#  with name nam in environment envir
data.frame.info <- function(nam, envir = .GlobalEnv) {
    DF <- get(nam, envir)
    cbind(data.frame = nam, 
          columns = names(DF),
          class = sapply(DF, function(col) class(col)[1]))
}

do.call(rbind, lapply(data.frame.names(), data.frame.info))
```

giving:

```
    data.frame columns class      
t   "df1"      "t"     "numeric"  
t2  "df1"      "t2"    "factor"   
t1  "df2"      "t1"    "logical"  
t4  "df2"      "t4"    "character"
dt  "df3"      "dt"    "Date"     
dt2 "df3"      "dt2"   "POSIXct"
```

**2)** If you just want to display information on the R console then this might be sufficient.  It makes use of `data.frame.names` above:

```
ls.str(pattern = paste(paste0("^", data.frame.names(), "$"), collapse = "|"))
```

giving:

```
df1 : 'data.frame':     1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ t : num 1
 $ t2: Factor w/ 1 level "c": 1
df2 : 'data.frame':     1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ t1: logi TRUE
 $ t4: chr "j"
df3 : 'data.frame':     1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ dt : Date, format: "2015-11-06"
 $ dt2: POSIXct, format: "2015-11-06 05:14:40"
```

Comment: Thanks, the 1) is exactly what I was looking for. The get() function is a great discovery.